# Ignore Case sql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2

I am trying to basically ignore the case sensitivity for my db2 sql select * query, so that I can populate the products to my catalogue page. Ex. If I type in my search bar 'squeege', I want the item 'Squeege' to populate, even if there is a difference in Upper/lower case. What is the best way to do this, based on the code I have below?

```
var searchProduct = "select * from LISTOFPRODUCTS where ITEM LIKE  '%" + searchValue + "%'"
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this could work:

```js
var searchProduct = "select * from LISTOFPRODUCTS where UPPER(ITEM) LIKE  UPPER('%" + searchValue + "%'")
```

Also the same with `LOWER()`

Note that the trick is parse both values to `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` to match them.

Comment: You are welcome! If issue is resolved, mark as accepted is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `LOWER()`.
For example:

```
var searchProduct = "select * from LISTOFPRODUCTS where LOWER(ITEM) LIKE  '%" + searchValue + "%'"
```

Comment: both this and upper seem to work like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html) which has a case-insensitive option `i`